# Vue 3 i18n Locale Not Updating (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm trying to change the Vue-i18n locale with a button click. But when I click on the button nothing happened. There is also no error at all. How to fix this?

```
<button v-on:click.prevent="setLocale('id')">Ind</button>
<button v-on:click.prevent="setLocale('en')">Eng</button>

import i18n from "../i18n";
const setLocale = (lang) => {
  i18n.global.locale = lang;
};
```

Comment: Did you add your i18n config to when initializing app.ts?

Comment: @DFXNguyễn yeah createApp(App).use(i18n)

Comment: There's not enough context to determine the problem. What is in `i18n.js`?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. A scarce snippet you posted isn't workable and doesn't show relevant things. The one thing that is wrong is that `i18n.global.locale`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be other things, but there's at least one mistake in the code. [`i18n.global.locale` is a ref](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#locale) and should be used as:

```
const setLocale = (lang) => {
  i18n.global.locale.value = lang;
};
```

It cannot be reactive the other way.

Comment: For standard Vue3 implementation, I think it leaves legacy mode ON, this calls for `i18n.global.locale= lang;` leave the value part out. It still becomes reactive anyway!

Answer (score 0):

in my case (Vue 3 + Composition API), I use

```
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

setup () {
  const i18n = useI18n();
  const setLocale = (lang) => {
    i18n.locale.value = lang;
  };
}
```